# Why im getting this error This line has a length of 118. Maximum allowed is 80 max-len?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Im trying to upload my function into firebase but getting  two errors that says

```
39:1    error    This line has a length of 123. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len
  39:111  warning  'context' is defined but never used                   @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  48:1    error    This line has a length of 118. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len
```

this is my code that I wanna upload

```
export const onConversationUpdated = functions.firestore.document("Conversations/{chatID}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    let data = change?.after.data();
        if (data) { 
            let members = data.members;
            let lastMessage = data.messages[data.messages.length - 1];
            for (let index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
                let uid = members[index];
                let remainingUserIDs = members
                .filter((u:string) => u != uid);
                remainingUserIDs.forEach((u:string) => {
                    return admin.firestore().collection("meinprofilsettings").doc(uid).collection("Conversations").doc(u).update({
                        "lastMessage": lastMessage.message,
                        "timestamp": lastMessage.timestamp,
                        "type": lastMessage.type,
                        "unseenCount": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        return null;
    });
```

The line is the first line and the line 48 is this line "remainingUserIDs.forEach((u:string) => { ....."

Hope anyone can help if you had more questions please leave a comment.

Comment: Off by 1 error? It's probably for the next line `return admin.firetore().collection/* ... */`. Or there is a bunch of whitespace at the end of line 48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum allowed characters per line is 80 as per the linter. Go to the lines +80 in length, #39 & #48 and make them 80 characters long, as per the error displayed. Or, edit your .eslintrc.js file to the rules you want.

Comment: no this not solving my problem I also set the line 39 to line 40 but still showing error line 39

Comment: @usinguser why not just break up your line to the 80 character limit?

Comment: Ok got it it just forget to save before running

Comment: What rule should we add in .eslintrc.js file to avoid this error. ?

Comment: @AmmarZahid I don't think you can change that, it's set by eslint. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: There's no option in that file